# Regex for unix paths

Tags: unix, regex, perl

What would be the correct perl regex for detecting only Unix paths?

```
./dir1/dir2/file.ext - invalid
./dir1/dir2/ - valid
./dir1/dir2 - valid
```

Comment: Why is the first path invalid? Dot is legal in directory name.

Comment: Those are all valid paths.  Also multiple slashes like ///dir1/dir2//dir3 are valid.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Trying to detect directories with a regex is almost certainly the wrong solution.  You are usually better off just testing to see if the path exists.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206320/how-do-i-distinguish-a-file-from-a-directory-in-perl

Comment: @choroba and Matt H I was not aware of that. Good to know. Zoredache I was trying to use regex to omit unix paths for Google Search Appliance (GSA), since it accepts regex. I'll stick with simple specific paths then.

Answer (score 4):

There is none.

There's no way to distinguish whether a basename is a file or directory by looking at the path alone.

Answer (score 1):

Do `man perlfunc` and look at the first set of functions under `Alphabetical Listing of Perl Functions`. There are a set of functions, beginning with `-`, that test what type of file/whatever a path refers to. The one you probably want is `-d`, which tests if a file refers to a directory.